# Mysql split comma separated results into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table where two columns are comma separated id's. For example

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
| name   | country_ids | region_ids |
+--------+-------------+------------+
| item 1 | 1,2,3       | 2,4        |
+--------+-------------+------------+
| item 2 | 2,3         | 1,4        |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

I would like to run a mysql query so the comma separated values in both columns are split into multiple rows.  So in the above example, the results would be

```
name     | country_id | region_id |
+--------+------------+-----------+
item 1   |  1         |  2        |
item 1   |  1         |  4        |
item 1   |  2         |  2        |
item 1   |  2         |  4        |
item 1   |  3         |  2        |
item 1   |  3         |  4        |
item 2   |  2         |  1        |
item 2   |  2         |  4        |
item 2   |  3         |  1        |
item 2   |  3         |  4        |
```

Is this possible in a mysql statement - even if I have to create a stored procedure on the fly?

THanks

Comment: That post answers the scenario where there is only one column with separated comma values. My question relates to two columns, which I am having trouble achieving

Comment: Just take an answer from the duplicate link, and split one column bringing alone the still CSV values from the other column.  Then, split the second column.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example. I understand the logic, but as I said, i am having trouble physically achieving it

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?.

Comment: MySQL version is 5.7.22

Comment: This is as close as I got before things started breaking. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kKT8uwPXZSHbLYUG4rskwv/0

Comment: Here a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vJMerGTLX7qk4QysNkXhJN/0) with an option that can give you some ideas, adjust as you need.

Comment: @wchiquito. That is perfect. Thanks for your help